# Convert PHP Array to a single Variable

Tags: php, arrays, email, variables, carbon-copy

What I'm trying to do is parse the CC addresses out of some mail headers using PHP, they come through as an array (oddly even if its just one address).  And I'd like to just convert the array into a single long variable.

So for instance if I had the following array:
array(bob@example.com, bill@example.com);

Then I want to convert that to a single variable that could be something like
'bob@example.com,bill@example.com'

I've tried several things and the main thing that I thought should have worked was the following:

```
$ccList[]=$headerinfo->cc;   

foreach( $ccList as $key=>$val ){
   $ccAddress .= $val.","; 
   }
Sys::log(LOG_ALERT,'CC Address is..'.$ccAddress);
```

but when I get that logfile it says "CC Address is...Array,"

Is there any way to accomplish what I'm wanting? I should note that as its CC addresses I won't always know if its 0 addresses or several or anywhere in between.

I've also tried a few things with print_r and var_dump but they didn't return the results I expected to see (email addresses).  I think var_dump still showed "Array" (or nothing) and print_r just said "CC Address is ...1".

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: First check using a var_dump what's in the $val var. Anyway I don't see how you initialize the $ccAddress var.

Comment: echo $key and $val. Be sure that you have the ccList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php take a look here.

```
$newccAddress = implode(",", $ccAddress);
```

Comment: When I echo key/val I get:
Key is..0 Val is..Array
but the output of your command is:
"newCC Address outside loop is.."

Comment: adapt implode method to your case. implode makes a single variable as you wanted but you problem is way different than creating a single variable. make sure what you get from $headerinfo->cc;

Comment: Yea, what I don't understand is when I print $headerinfo->cc I get "Array" but when I print var_dump($headerinfo->cc) I get nothing. The issue is confused by this being done via a function so I have to print to a dashboard log just to see the results.  Doesn't the output of "Array" suggest that its not empty though?

Comment: sigh, I went up further in my code and investigated imap_headerinfo. Turns out there is both cc and ccaddress that you can use.  I just used ccaddress instead and its giving me exactly what I want.  thanks Anyway guys, implode was what I needed otherwise!

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `implode` function.  As in, `$result = implode(',', array(bob@example.com, bill@example.com))`, which would return your result.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Answer (score 0):

In this example, you can use `implode()`, off cause

If to speak about "Converting PHP Array to a single Variable" *in general*, it's where you'll want to take a look at `array_reduce()` beast.